Windows Move to Workspace 1 After Turning Monitor Off and On in Elementary OS 7.1
I am experiencing an issue on Elementary OS 7.1 where all my open windows move to Workspace 1 whenever I turn my monitor off and then back on. I have different screens assigned to different workspaces, and this behavior disrupts my workflow.
Here's my setup:
Elementary OS 7.1
Single-monitor configuration with different windows on different workspaces

Steps to reproduce:
Assign windows to different workspaces.
Turn off the monitor.
Turn the monitor back on.

After following these steps, all windows are relocated to Workspace 1.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there any known fixes or workarounds to prevent windows from moving to Workspace 1 after turning the monitor off and on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
